# Xen dom0 cannot connect to the internet

Tags: xen, linux-mint, bridge

I configured a Linux Mint 17 host O/S to install Xen as per the following guide

[Xen Project Beginner's Guide](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Project_Beginners_Guide#What_is_this_Xen_Project_software_all_about.3F)

Now, after configuring the network interfaces as instructed, I rebooted the machine. I can see that the bridge has an IP assigned to it via DHCP, but I cannot connect to the internet.

I can even successfully ping to the gateway, but not any other address.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my /etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
```

Comment: Sounds like it didn't acquire a default route from the DHCP server...

Comment: I did check that. Running route shows the configuration is fine

Comment: was there any update on this case?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I only added `eth0` and `eth1` interfaces into the bridge

```
bridge name  bridge id          STP enabled    interfaces
br0          8000.00259e1c426c  no              eth0
                                                eth1
```

But there was an interface called `vif3.0` which has to be included into the bridge interface. So, i did this

```
brctl addif br0 vif3.0
```

Everything works fine.